# how to resolve dependency when comparing schema in TFS for SQL Server project or when creating .DACPAC files in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs

I have SQL server project setup in TFS. when i am trying to compare schema from source control project with Target project, i am getting some error on Unresolved reference. so i tried to add database reference from using "Add Database Reference" dialog box and it is asking me to add .DACPAC file.

to create .DACPAC file i went in SSMS and right clicked on DB and selected Tasks->Extract Data-tier Application option. it is getting failed because it can not resolve dependency for some of database objects (which uses linked server connection). so my question is how can i resolve this dependency so that i can add .DACPAC file in TFS to compare schema and generate scripts for deployment from TFS. i am using Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle it would be to also create a dacpac for the database the other end of the linked server and add a database reference as "Other Server, Other Database".

Instead of SSMS I would create a new ssdt project in ssdt and import each database as it will be more reliable than the ssms extract.

Ed